# Does setting the deadline for a swap using `block.timestamp` inside the contract actually do anything?

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I saw this in a codebase I'm working on and was wondered if this even does anything, because it doesn't seem like it does. Wouldn't `block.timestamp` be set when it's included in a block? Or maybe there is something I'm missing.

[image: swap function with Uniswap V2]

Answer (score 1):

The swap router requires that the block the transaction is mined has timestamp  less or equal the `deadline` argument from the function call: https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol#L19
So yes, the `deadline` argument must have a valid value even if called from another smart contract, and using for example 0 will cause transactions to be reverted.

That said, the spirit of the question is probably more about what values are valid and would one use `block.timestamp + 60` rather than simply `block.timestamp` as the argument? To my knowledge, there is no specific reason to add exactly 60, but adding a small positive number to the block's timestamp seems to be a common pattern, potentially to make the reader's job easier. If `block.timestamp` is used as the argument, then one must verify in the Uniswap's source code whether the check is `deadline >= block.timestamp` rather than `deadline > block.timestamp`. If `block.timestamp + 1` is used then both ways would work.

Alternatively, this is simply a leftover from a code initially written to be called off-chain, where this would mean that the transaction must be mined within one minute or be rejected.

Comment: Actually it makes a lot of sense to use a `deadline`. Lets say you submit a trade with a low gas price and the price goes up by 10% after you made the transactions. Now your `amountOutMin` is completely off and can be sandwiched.